# Symfony3 Export To Production

Tags: php, apache2, symfony, production-environment

I have a server running on apache2 with some virtual hosts and I want to deploy a Symfony3 application on it. However, I cannot deploy it correctly to the production environment, it works perfectly on development environment. Whenever I do execute

```
sudo composer install --no-dev --optimize-autoloader
```

I get the error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle' not found in /my/path/app/AppKernel.php on line 25
> Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handling the post-install-cmd event terminated with an exception

```
[RuntimeException]
An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle'not found in /my/path/app/AppKernel.php on line 25.
```

After getting this error I went to read the documentation again and it said that I need to export this the Symfony environment to production. So I did that:

```
export SYMFONY_ENV=prod
```

After that I executed the `composer install` command again but, same results.

Some people on Stackoverflow (and other sources) said that I need to clear my cache by executing

```
sudo bin/console cache:clear --env=prod
```

So I did that but same results. Anyone any idea?

Other solutions tried:
Actually it works great whenever I execute the command this way:

```
sudo SYMFONY_ENV=prod composer install --no-dev --optimize-autoloader
```

However, whenever everything was installed correctly, I went to try to visit the URL and I got a 500. So I went to the Apache2 logs to check if something was wrong and I saw the same `RuntimeException` again.

**EDIT**

So I've also followed the instructions of this [link](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#checking-symfony-application-configuration-and-setup) but unfortunately, same results. I also checked if I've got everything installed correctly such as ACL and I did.

I also did an `getfacl /my/path/var/cache` and it showed the correct information based on this [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-symfony-application-to-production-on-ubuntu-14-04).

**EDIT #2**

I've also already run `php bin/symfony_requirements` and it showed me that 'My system is ready to run Symfony Projects', even after `php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain what the problem could be, but since this is a new deploy, make sure you have setup the correct install requirements. For apache, normally the user is apache and group is apache.

In a production environment an easy way to set the correct owner:group is the following command:

```
$sudo chown -R apache:apache /var/www/html/test.karljohnchow.com/
```

Also, this link:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#checking-symfony-application-configuration-and-setup

Describes how to setup the ACL permissions on Linux (and MacOS), and the var directory needs special permissions.

Make sure you check those things and see if that helps.

**Edit #2.**
I saw your comment. One of those links is for Symfony2 and it's old. I don't suggest using references that are old. They may refer to Symfony2 which is different than Symfony3.

Take a look at this link:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/deployment/tools.html

Have you run the `php bin/symfony_requirements` command yet? This is important that this passes. It'll point out problems.
Also the command to clear (and warm-up) the cache is:

```
$ php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug
```

That's different from what you show above.

Comment: Hey! I've also followed these instructions for `var/cache` and `var/logs`. But nothing :( See my edited question for more info.

Comment: I edited my post. Take a look - I hope it helps, otherwise I'm not sure.

Comment: Thank you! I've obviously adjusted the commands to make it compatible with Symfony3. And yes I already run both. But unfortunately :(